# Custom Font Load Inconsistently on PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova

I've built a PhoneGap application that uses FontAwesome as a part of it's user interface. When I load the application to my iPad the fonts display correctly about 1/2 of the time. When working I can close the app and then start it and then they stop displaying. Restarting the app again they will work again.  Any ideas??? I'm currently running PhoneGap 2.4, since I have a custom plug-in I'd prefer not upgrade.

Comment: are you loading the fonts from an external source or locally?

Comment: Locally, sorry I should have mentioned that.